# Is it possible to call Google Cloud APIs from Google Colab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

When I try from a Colab, e.g.

```
from google.cloud import translate
client = translate.Client()
client.translate("Where is the store?", target_language='zh')
```

I get the following error ...

```
# Cloud Translation API has not been used in project 12345678901 before or it is disabled. 
# Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/overview?project=12345678901
# then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

... (for another value of `12345678901`) & following the link gives me a generic "Failed to load" error on GCP.

I've not used the Google Cloud APIs before and after some searching online can't find any examples of how to enable these APIs with Colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

this notebook seems to work for Google Translate API

try these steps

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hPH7skySCZR-ZMJ6TmYLN1ug6vbq2cpb#scrollTo=2w4bHiuYXywg